# Create event as delegate outlook API

Tags: outlook, ms-office, office365, outlook-restapi, outlook-calendar

Based on the impediment I encountered on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462270/setting-event-organizer-with-outlook-calendar-rest-api) question I am asking the following:

Is it possible to create an event on someone else's outlook (if that person assigned me as their delegate) using the Outlook Calendar API, when I am the one who is impersonated on my application?

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot do this currently. Delegate access is not supported by the REST API. The impersonation rights assigned to the app only grant access to the user's mailbox.